# Getting a strange error from winnt.h?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, camera

I'm trying to write an x2 camera driver for a Hamamatsu camera in  Visual Studio 2015.  The X2 driver template already has windows.h included as an external dependency, but when trying to include a necessary header file, it throws an error that windows.h is not included (along with 80 or so errors of function calls that therefore don't exist).  But when I include windows.h, I think it's causing a double include and is throwing this error:

```
Severity: Error (active)
Code: none 
Description: expected an identifier Project :x2camera
File: c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\um\winnt.h
Line: 524
```

I'm really new to working with Visual Studio projects - how can I include windows.h into the file so it can get the functions and declarations it needs without actually including it and causing a double inclusion?  Like I said, it's in the "project dependencies" list, and I think it's being included in another file (but I'm having a hard time finding that).

Or is that not even my problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note: _windows.h_ (and all the other _VStudio_ header files) have the [#include guard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx.aspx) to avoid multiple inclusion.

Comment: I was pretty sure that was the case, so I don't understand why it would be throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

​No idea what the problem was but I somehow managed to get it to compile.  I think it needed to be included elsewhere first, then built, then included where it needed to be... which doesn't make sense honestly but maybe it was an error with how the inclusion was functioning.

Either way, my question is now resolved, though the questions that now arise such as "why the heck did this work" are baffling.